# Trying to convert XLS to CSV and CSV to XLS using VBScript. Receiving error: 800A03EC (Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class)

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I'm trying to open a CSV then use the SaveAs method to save it as an XLS. Also vice-versa in another script. I accidentally had the file format codes wrong before and was not getting this error. The CSV would in fact open. I accidentally had made the CSV format 2 (which is actually SYLK) and the XLS, 6 (which is actually CSV).

I've looked all over, and most of what I can find has to do with using an incorrect argument (which I have checked multiple times). The rest is for ASP, and suggests changing permissions in Component Services (which probably wouldn't be an issue anyway, since I can get the Open method to work with different formats).

So I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. If I can't even use the Open method, then I'm kind of stuck. If it was as simple as thee SaveAs method not working for this task, I could get around that. But I need to be able to open an XLS using the Open method (since I'm also trying to do XLS to CSV). CSV to XLS can be fixed another way, probably, since the Open method seems to work sometimes.

Anyway, my code for the CSV to XLS is below. The XLS to CSV is essentially identical to this. It just flips the format codes and uses different paths for the files.

```
strName = "MidCSVTemp.csv"
strSaveName = Month(Now) & "." & Day(Now) & "." & Year(Now) & ".xls"
strPath = "C:\Users\adam\Documents\" & strName
strSavePath = "C:\Users\adam\Documents\" & strSaveName

'Options for Workbook.Open
intUpdateLinks = 0
boolReadOnly = False
intFormat = 6

'Options for SaveAs
intFileFormat = 56

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath,intUpdateLinks,boolReadOnly,intFormat)
Call objWorkBook.SaveAs(strSavePath,intFileFormat)
Call objWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `SaveAs` _after_ the workbook has been closed?

Comment: That would be a typo. I copy and pasted something and put it in the wrong the place. It was originally before closing it. I guess I missed that since I've been trying to figure out the opening issue. But I can't see how that would make it not allow me to use the Open method.

Comment: Just trying to understand what's going on here. You're also using `intFormat` in your `Open()` function when you declared a variable named `strFormat`. Or is that another typo?

Comment: Yeah. Just another typo. It was originally intFormat. But I lost the enumeration for Excel's file formats. And MSDN didn't list any enumeration. So I decided to just try what was listed on MSDN (which were strings), even though I was nearly positive it wasn't right. I just got so frustrated that I forgot to change it back before posting it here.

Comment: And is where is `strName` defined? I don't see that anywhere. You have something called `strNastrName` that appears to be the name of a CSV file. Is that what you're trying to open? Can you edit your question and fix all the typos? It's tough to provide any help when I see so many errors and can't tell which are legitimate errors and which are just typos.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'll clean it up. I typed this up after I got really frustrated from the lack of resources via Google. I also didn't get a lot of sleep last night. The NastrName thing actually occurred while I was typing this question. I accidentally hit an arrow key and didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using the `Format` parameter of the `Workbooks.Open()` method like it's the `FileFormat` parameter. It shouldn't be `xlCSV` `(6)`, which is a `FileFormat` constant. According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819%28v=office.15%29.aspx), `Format` should be one of the following values:

- 1 = Tabs
- 2 = Commas
- 3 = Spaces
- 4 = Semicolons
- 5 = Nothing
- 6 = Custom

Since you're passing a value of `6`, it's expecting that you also include the `Delimiter` argument. And since you're not including it, you're getting an error.

You should be able to open a CSV without specifying the `Format` parameter (Excel seemed to guess the delimiter correctly for me without having to specify it). But, to be safe, pass a value of 2 for a comma-delimited (CSV) file.

```
intFormat = 2
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath,intUpdateLinks,boolReadOnly,intFormat)
```

Comment: Yep. That did it. I can't believe I missed something that simple. I must not have been paying enough attention when I was changing that value. It doesn't help that there's also a property called Delimiter. Anyway, thanks for the help. I'll try to read the documentation a bit more closely next time I have an error.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck on your project.